# “implicit declaration of function '…' is invalid in C99”

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to make a simple soundboard app for the iphone, but have come across some troubles including `implicit definition of function '...' is invalid in C99`, about a few different functions.

My .h file looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController

{

}

- (IBAction) Jesus: (id) sender;

@end
```

and my .m file code looks like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (IBAction) NamedAction:(id)sender: (id) sender
{
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Jesus",
    CSFTR("WAV") NULL);
    if  (soundFileURLRef) {
        CFStringRef url = CFURLGetString(soundFileURLRef);
        NSLog(@"string for URl is %@", (__bridge NSString *) url);
    }

    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

}


@end
```

The error message I'm getting is:

> Called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer

Comment: Joe, perhaps have a think about what you call your functions in future. While I'm not offended myself, there *is* a case that a large chunk of people *would* find it offensive.

Answer (score 3):

`- (IBAction) NamedAction:(id)sender: (id) sender`

has to variables named the same, probably the 2nd is a typo:

`- (IBAction) NamedAction: (id) sender`

And

`soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Jesus",
    CSFTR("WAV") NULL);`

possibly missing a comma before the NULL?

`soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Jesus",
    CSFTR("WAV"), NULL);`

Comment: This is is. Also capitalizing a method name is not good practice at all.

Answer (score 1):

What function is CSFTR? Apparently the compiler has never heard of it, which is what it is telling (in a rather weird way. Before C99, using a function without declaration was in implicit declaration, C99 removed that).

Could it be that you are trying to use a macro with a name that is just slightly different?

I'd really recommend that you avoid using Core Foundation functions. Especially since NSBundle and CFBundle can behave differently. Core Foundation and ARC especially is a combination that can make your brain hurt and can lead to memory leaks or crashes, unless you *really* know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add a framework to your project which i suspect is AudioToolBox

Answer (score 0):

Add -Wno-implicit-function-declaration in Other warnings flag and you will be able to compile the code. Although its not a good solution but it will work.